# Less CSS does not work on a HTTP server

Tags: css, less

Basic Less CSS code works fine when run from local file system:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" type="text/css" />
<script src="less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>
```

But once I move my code to a HTTP server, Less CSS becomes unable to find the stylesheet file and all the styling gets broken. The server (App Engine) returns *.less as "octetstream" actually. I tried to copy "style.less" to "style.txt" but with no success.

What does Less CSS needs to work on servers?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how less operates but my guess is that it uses ajax to fetch it and then parse it. So maybe it's a cross-domain issue?

Answer (score 4):

That depends heavily on your http server. But you can map in most webservers `suffixes` to `mime types` per configuration.

In apache something like this could be a solution

```
AddType text/css .less
```

See [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html)